# ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers

Tags: configparser

I am trying to fetch data from a `.cfg` (configuration file) in python but I am always getting the error

```
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

[The screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOcPf.png)

Here is the link for the .cfg file:

http://www.mediafire.com/file/66k9m7trxo7krx9/a.cfg/file

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the contents if the config file.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/66k9m7trxo7krx9/a.cfg/file

Comment: this is the link for .cfg file.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have parameters without section, e.g.:

```
name1 = value1
name2 = value2
```

According [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#supported-ini-file-structure) there should be a section.

I may suggest the following solutions:

#### Add section explicitly

Add section in ini file, e.g:

```
[default]
name1 = value1
name2 = value2
```

#### Add section implicitly

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
with open('config.ini') as stream:
    parser.read_string('[default]\n' + stream.read())

# now you can use it for parameters without section
print(parser.get('default', 'name1'))
```

Comment: Many people want just get key-value pairs easily and the implicit method does just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The ConfigParser module assumes that config files have section headers. Section headers are used to keep configurations of one type together. Write `[Default]` in the first line of your configuration file. This will tell ConfigParser that there is only one header and that is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding JSON file instead of config file in format:

```
[OPTIONS]
option1 = foo
option2 = bar
```